# Dectect OS from ping with bash script?

Tags: bash

1. Problem: So recently i want to try to write a simple script to detect OS from a ping script( base on TTL(time-to-live))
2. Things i have tried: i have try some things like this

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                    

sn=${1:-$1}

for host in $(seq 1 255); do
                            
    ttlstr=$(ping -c1 -w1 $sn.$host | grep -o 'ttl=[0-9][0-9]*') || {
        printf "%s is Offline\n" "$sn.$host"
        continue;
    }
    ttl="${ttlstr#*=}"           
    printf "%s is Online, ttl=%d\n" "$sn.$host" "$ttl"
    if [ $ttl -eq 64 ]
            then
                echo "Operating is Linux"
            elif [ $ttl -eq 128 ]
            then
                echo "Operating is Windows"
            else
                echo "Operating is IOS"
                fi

done
```

3. So as you can see it can ping every ip with the given Ip address. But if user want to enter: `192.168.1.0/24` how can i solve that ?

Lastly, thanks for your answer :D

Comment: Unless you want to write your own parser, why not use a CLI tool like ipcalc?

Comment: I have an assigntment about bash script :D
Tks for your answer :D

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `${1:-$1}`? `${1:-x}` means the value of `$1`, if it is defined and not null or `x` otherwise. But your `x` is `$1` and that makes the expression mean "use $1 if it is set or $1 otherwise".

Comment: @axiac thank you for pointing out my mistake. Im pretty new to bash so i still make mistake :D. Still trying to improve my Bash skill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script :

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                    

if [ -z $1 ] ; then 
    echo "Please enter ip address"
    exit 1
fi 

function print_os_type() {
    case $2  in 
       64) echo "$1 Linux" ;;
       128) echo "$1  Windows" ;;
       *) echo "$1 Unknown os type";;
    esac
}

function get_ttl() {
    ping -c1 -w1 $1 | grep ttl | awk '{print $6}' | tr -d "ttl="
}

if [ ! -z $2 ] ; then 
    IPS=$(nmap -sL -n $1/$2 | grep report | awk '{print $5}')  
    for I in ${IPS[@]}
    do
        ttl=$(get_ttl $I) 
        print_os_type $I $ttl
    done
else
    ttl=$(ping -c1 -w1 $1 | grep ttl | awk '{print $6}' | tr -d "ttl=")
    print_os_type $1 $ttl
fi
```

Usage :

```
./script.sh 192.168.1.1 #For single ip 
./script.sh 172.16.10.0 24 #For subnet of ips
```

or simply use this command :

```
nmap -n -O 192.168.1.0/24 | grep 'OS details'
```

**Note :**
this is horrible idea for using ttl to detect os type .
some peoples like me change this ttl manually :

```
root@HOSTNAME:~# echo 110 >  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl
root@HOSTNAME:~# ping -c1 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=110 time=0.069 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.069/0.069/0.069/0.000 ms
```

Comment: Well, that said, if you are having `nmap` then just detect OS with `nmap`.

Comment: @mah454 But if I dont have nmap the script wont work. How do you solve that ?  thank you :D

Comment: @Ta219 too hard man ! please see this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986879/bash-script-to-list-all-ips-in-prefix